# How to run nbconvert on notebook in google colaboratory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, nbconvert

I have a simple jupyter notebook, say `foo.ipynb`.  I wish simply to run `nbconvert` in the usual way: on my local machine I would execute `!jupyter nbconvert foo.ipynb` in the notebook itself, or `jupyter notebook foo.ipynb` in a shell.  On Google Colaboratory, this does not work.  Of course this is because `foo.ipynb` is not running locally on the drive, but the usual methods to connect Drive and Colab are not working in this case. **Question: is running `nbconvert` on a Colab notebook possible from within a Colab notebook (as in `!jupyter nbconvert foo.ipynb`), and if so, how?** I have tried:

1. (The Colab File Menu options don't do the necessary export, which is why I need `nbconvert`.  Downloading to a local machine and running `nbconvert` is also not an option here.)
2. The simplest attempt to link to the file directly (when authenticated) `!jupyter nbconvert 'https://colab.research.google.com/drive/2pexUcovcblu1Api0F0NezyhZyN2MEMWLhs5ujm?authuser=2`
3. This SO post: [Google Colab: how to read data from my google drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48376580/google-colab-how-to-read-data-from-my-google-drive)
   But again no luck, since it can’t seem to find the file and `nbconvert` only takes a filename.
4. Other approaches suggested in SO posts, including: [Is it possible to import my own modules into a google-colaboratory notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219341/is-it-possible-to-import-my-own-modules-into-a-google-colaboratory-notebook?noredirect=1&lq=1) , [Import data into Google Colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986398/import-data-into-google-colaboratory?rq=1) , [How to run a downloaded Jupyter notebook on Google Colaboratory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48961866/how-to-run-a-downloaded-jupyter-notebook-on-google-colaboratory)

How can I accomplish `nbconvert` on a colab notebook, within the notebook?  I can verify that `nbconvert` is available on colab; it's just not able to find the file under any of the above approaches (so far as I have been able).

Answer (score 4):

1. Upload your `foo.ipynb` to your home directory on Colaboratory.
   (The home directory is `/content/`)
2. Run: 
   `!jupyter nbconvert --to html /content/foo.ipynb`
3. Download `foo.html` to your local machine.

Comment: This works well although you need to install some things first if you want pdf output. Do this in a cell in Colab `!sudo apt-get update`
`!sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-generic-recommended`. Then run this to convert `!jupyter nbconvert --to pdf /content/foo.ipynb`