# Can't download ipynb file

Tags: python, file

I need to download an ipynb file and so I am trying to set colaboratory as the default app to open (because when I try it says "Please install an app, or if one is already installed, create an association in the default app setting page". But when I go in control panel/Programs/Default Programs/Associate a file type or protocol with a program/Choose default apps by file type , I can't find .ipynd files. What should I do ?
( I am on windows 10)

Comment: You stated you are trying to open a **.ipynb** file, but then can not associate it with a **.ipynd** file. Is this correct or a typo?

Comment: If you're trying to open the file, it's already downloaded, no? (I haven't used Windows in years.)

Answer (score -1):

Go to Control Panel by pressing the Windows Button + R and typing cmd followed by Enter, and type `pip install ipython`.

This should allow you to open .ipynb files.

To set the default app for opening specific files, right-click the file (in this case any .ipynb file), press Open With, hover the cursor over Show More, press Choose Another App, press Show More (if the desired app isn't there), select your app, press Always use this app to open .ipynb files, and press OK. This should set the app you want as the default app.

Comment: *"Go to Control Panel by pressing the Windows Button + R and typing cmd followed by Enter"* -- Huh? Control Panel?

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to load a .ipynb notebook on Colab.
If you are trying to load something from a github page or google drive then you may follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48961866/how-to-run-a-downloaded-jupyter-notebook-on-google-colaboratory)

If you are trying to create a .ipynb file yourself, you can easily do it from within colab by using the option File-> Download .ipynb
[image: .ipynb from Google Colab]

If you are trying to open, modify and run an .ipynb file locally on your windows PC (without colab) then you will have to install IPython/[Jupyter lab](https://jupyter.org/install).